# CategoryPublisher does not find org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I'm trying to publish a `category.xml` with the help of `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher` in a maven tycho build. Unfortunately I keep getting errors about `org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle`.

I found various posts here on SO about this topic, but they all refer to the eclipse GUI which is not relevant here.

maven properties:

```xml
<properties>
    <tycho.version>2.5.0</tycho.version>
    <equinox.launcher.version>1.6.300.v20210813-1054</equinox.launcher.version>
</properties>
```

exec-maven-plugin definition:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>publish-category</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-jar</argument>
                    <argument>${settings.localRepository}/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-bundles-external/${tycho.version}/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_${equinox.launcher.version}.jar</argument>
                    <argument>-consolelog</argument>
                    <argument>-application</argument>
                    <argument>org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher</argument>
                    <argument>-categoryDefinition</argument>
                    <argument>file:/${project.basedir}/category.xml</argument>
                    <argument>-metadataRepository</argument>
                    <argument>file:/${project.build.directory}/repository/</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Error message:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
!SESSION 2022-06-16 11:59:58.380 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_CH
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher -categoryDefinition file:/C:\devxxx\projekte\yxcz\yxcz-client\ch.xxx.yxcz.rcp.target/category.xml -metadataRepository file:/C:\devxxx\projekte\yxcz\yxcz-client\ch.xxx.yxcz.rcp.target\target/repository/
Command-line arguments:  -consolelog -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher -categoryDefinition file:/C:\devxxx\projekte\yxcz\yxcz-client\ch.xxx.yxcz.rcp.target/category.xml -metadataRepository file:/C:\devxxx\projekte\yxcz\yxcz-client\ch.xxx.yxcz.rcp.target\target/repository/

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-06-16 12:00:01.734
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
```

Comment: That looks like a dirty hack. Which documentation did you follow? Why not using [`tycho-p2-publisher:publish-categories`](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-publisher-plugin/publish-categories-mojo.html)?

Comment: I have packaging `eclipse-target-definition`. As far as I understand `tycho-p2-publisher:publish-categories` only works with packaging `eclipse-plugin`

Comment: Not sure what you trying to say. It looks like you try to run the Eclipse Tycho Maven plugin as it would be the Eclipse platform runtime. Could you please tell why you are doing it in this way? Which documentation did you follow?

Comment: I'm not sure that the Eclipse plug-in stuff in tycho-bundles-external is sufficient to run this. Try pointing to a launcher in a complete Eclipse install.